# Windows 10 drivers for Bluetooth Apple keyboard

Tags: windows-10, drivers, keyboard, bluetooth, boot-camp

I am trying to install the drivers for my Apple keyboard on a non-apple computer (a dell). I have tried installing the bootcamp drivers directly from File Explorer, command line, and trying to update the driver manualy, but there is no `.inf` file to tell Device Manager that there are any drivers

I have the newest bootcamp files from Apple's site

I'm trying to get the media keys, and brightness to work only when pressing <kbd>fn</kbd>, I can use the normal keys fine without any special drivers

The Bootcamp manager is installed and can manage the keyboard checkmark, but nothing else (as I don't have the apple efi)

here is a picture of my keyboard:

[image: Apple Wireless keyboard Model No.: A1314]

Comment: It's not gonna happen. Boot Camp drivers are for apple hardware running Windows, not for random windows hardware to recognise Apple peripherals.

Comment: @Tetsujin I have the apple Bluetooth driver installed and it's using my Bluetooth card just fine

Comment: Not sure how that works. You have a non-apple BT card, it works on a PC running Windows... chances would be it's using whichever drivers Windows assigned to it, not ones made for a different card in a different machine - a lot of them are Broadcomm, though, so it just might by chance have worked.

Comment: @Tetsujin, it is a Broadcomm BT card close enough to the ones in apple, so it works fine, it actually seems to work better than the ones made specifically for it